# If then switch in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to achieve this

```
if a?
  switch a
    'hello'
  else 'hi'
```

How to chain an if statement with switch statement if the condition isn't null or undefined?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your switch syntax is wrong. Something like that might be what you are looking for:

```
f = (a) ->
    if a?
        switch a
            when 'bonjour'
                'hello'
            else
                'yo'
    else
        'hi'

console.log f null
console.log f 'bonjour'
console.log f 'guten tag'
```

Producing:

```
sh$ coffee t.coffee 
hi
hello
yo
```

Please note you can have an `else` close both for the `switch` statement (where it denotes the *default* case) and for the `if` statement.

Depending your needs, you might want to write the other way around:

```
f = (a) ->
    switch a
        when 'bonjour'
            'hello'
        else
            if a? then 'yo' else 'hi'
```

Or even get completely rid of the `if`:

```
f = (a) ->
    switch a
        when 'bonjour'
            'hello'
        when null, undefined
            'hi'
        else
            'yo'
```

Answer (score -1):

That works. I found out that I have an spacing error.

Comment: your answer should contain the solution: corrected indenting of the else clause.